# Odoo not accessible via LAN or WAN

Tags: odoo, ubuntu-16.04

I have a weird issue that I cannot replicate.
I have Odoo 8 on Ubuntu Server 16.04.
I can access Odoo via localhost:8069 when at the servers console. 
I cannot access via 192.168.1.111:8069 via the server console or any other machine on the network.
I also cannot access via external IP.
I can ping the servers IP just fine from any other machine on LAN.
I can access the servers Apache html via local network.
I have port forwarded 8069 and opened the routers firewall.
I had a failed install and configuration of Nginx, but was removed.
Any ideas I am missing?

Comment: have you solved this?